# Webpack moves images regardless it component nested routes

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am using components with `<img src>` inside routes.

```
import myImg from './img.png'
<img src={myImg}>
```

Webpack`s build move all files to the`dist` folder, including images from components.

The problem is it moves images to the root of `dist` e.g. `dist/img.png`.

But also webpack rewrite images paths in HTML with component routes e.g. 
`<img src="/path/img.png">`.

It bring all images from nested routes to 404.

I need to force webpack move images accordingly its routes or write `src` path in HTML without routes.

How should I do that?

## router

```js
const router = (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path='/'
              component={App}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    router,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

## webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    watch  : true,
    entry  : {
        app: [
            'babel-polyfill',
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx')
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output : {
        filename: 'bundle-[hash].js',
        path    : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]-[hash].css'),
    ],
    module : {
        rules: [
            {
                test   : /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use    : 'babel-loader',
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(less|css)$/,
                use : ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    {
                        use: [
                            {loader: 'css-loader'},
                            {loader: 'resolve-url-loader'},
                            {loader: 'less-loader'},
                        ]
                    }
                ),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use : [
                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried including a folder name in `file-loader`? like that for example: `name=someFolder/[name]-[hash].[ext]`

Comment: @Sag1v Which folder name? 
Each component have its own folder with its own images.
Or do you mean `dist` output folder?

Comment: `folderName` will be a new folder holding all the images under the root `dist`. don't forget, after you builds the app you no longer has a folder structure of components and each folder per component. it's all inside 1 `bundle.js` file (unless you configure it to split files of course).

Comment: if you want to include the original path you can do it with `[path]` : `name=[path][name]-[hash].[ext]`. see the docs: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#examples

Comment: @Sag1v Yes, I can use `[path]`, but it doesn\`t resolve problem that I get image files as `path/img.png` and HTML as `<img src="myRoute/path/img.png">` which went me into 404. Because there is no folder `dist/myRoute`. That is what my question is about.